Dimension of a linear subspace of $2^S$ spanned by $100$ singletons?
Consider some set $\mathbf{S}$ containing $2024$ elements. On $2^\mathbf{S}$, define two operations, the addition and the multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, as
$$
A + B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)
$$
and
$$
1 X = X, \quad 0 X = \emptyset.
$$
Consider also the minimal subspace $\mathbf{P}$ of $2^\mathbf{S}$ containing specific $100$ pairwise distinct single-element subsets of $\mathbf{S}$.

Check that $2^\mathbf{S}$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
Find the dimension of the subspace $\mathbf{P}$.

I solved 1 but I have no idea about 2. Gut feeling says that the dimension is $100$, but I'm not sure.

Thank you! I updated my question.


Note that $2^S$
can be viewed more simply as the $|S|$
-dimensional vector space of maps from S
to $\Bbb Z_2$.
"The minimal subspace
containing $T$" (where $T$ is some given subset of a vector space) is more usually and shortly called "the subspace spanned by $T$". 3) My advice to replace "distinct" by "disjoint" was not justified: for singletons, it is equivalent.


A $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is a set of $n$-tuples that satisfy the standard properties of a vector space. How do you define a vector space generated from the power set of a set and $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

@TedBlack 1) A finite dimensional vector space is not necessarily a set of tuples. $\Bbb F^n$ is only a prototype thereof. 2) The two natural $\Bbb Z_2$-vector space operations on a powerset were defined by the OP.

@AnneBauval I still do not understand what kind of vector space these operations (subset addition and multiplication of each subset by $\sf 0$ and $\sf 1$) define. Can you provide examples of elements of this vector space?

@Thuja How did you prove (in question 1) that $2^S$ is finite dimensional? Didn't you find a natural basis for it? This should have helped you for question 2.

@TedBlack I do not understand your question. Just check that these two operations satisfy all the "vector space axioms", i.e. the conditions required for $(2^S,+,\cdot)$ to be called a $\Bbb Z_2$-vector space. The 'elements of this vector space' are of course the elements of $2^S$, i.e. the subsets of $S$.

@AnneBauval perhaps as an educational exercise you can do a short writeup for question 1. It will illustrate the concept of $({\sf 2}^S,+,\cdot)$ as a vector space quite nicely.

? This is rather the OP's job, since they claimed having solved question 1. And it would not be an "illustration of the concept". Just a proof of the claim. But it is  tedious. I find it quicker to argue that it is a vector space because it is isomorphic to an already known one (see my first comment above).

Yes, I can prove that it is vector space. And seems that single-element subsets are basis.

Indeed, the set $U$ of all singletons is a basis! (hence any subset $T\subseteq U$ is linearly independent, whence a basis of $P:=\operatorname{span}(T)$, which solves question 2). And $\dim(2^S)=|U|=|S|$.

Thanks. Today I have learned that every finite set is a vector space of dimension equal to its cardinality. Can someone now explain to me how 100 disjoint subsets of $2^S$ generate a subspace $P$? I am thinking that if $A,B \in P$ then $A+B=A \cup B \notin P$.

@AnneBauval thank you very much, now I realised it completely.

@TedBlack "every finite set is a vector space of dimension equal to its cardinality": not exactly. Rather: the powerset of $S$ is a vector space of dimension $|S|$. As for your question: any $100$ subsets of $\mathbf S$ (i.e. elements of $2^S$) span a subspace $P$, for the general reason that any $100$ vectors of a vector space $V$ span a subspace of $V$.

@AnneBauval I think we all agree that any subset of a set $S$ is a composition of its elements. But sometimes using terminology like 'vector space' and 'basis' is a bit over the top. Also defining a subset as a 'subspace' is a bit problematic; the power set of a subset is closed under addition but the subset itself is not.

"Over the top"? The terminology is fine. What precisely don't you understand in my previous comment? Some subsets of the vector space $2^S$ are subspaces, others are not. If $T\subseteq S$, $2^T$ is a subspace of $2^S$, but $T$ itself being closed under addition is neither true nor false: it is meaningless.

@AnneBauval any 100 independent vectors of a vector space $V$ span a subspace of the same dimension. Anyway I think our comments probably resemble those of a theological seminar in the Middle Ages...

I wrote "any $100$
vectors of a vector space $V$
span a subspace of $V$" because you were asking "how 100 [disjoint] subsets of $2^S$
generate a subspace" (which was incorrectly formulated and I explained why). Obviously, if 100 vectors are independent, the dimension of the subspace they span is $100$. If everything is finally clear to you, I am happy and I don't mind your last sentence.

The $100$ pairwise disjoint singletons are linearly independent, since a linear combination of any $99$ of them is disjoint from the last one. So the $100$ elements form a basis for their span. Therefore the dimension is $100$.

+1. Another argument is that every element of $P$ can be written uniquely as a 'linear combination' of these singletons, i.e. as a union of some of them.
